# How to use a GLSL shader in Android

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I'm new to the world of shaders especially in Android. I want to apply a GLSL shader to an image or a video in Android and see how it looks like. [This repo](https://github.com/quic/snapdragon-gsr) has a few shaders that I would like to try. How can I use these within an Android app and apply them to an image?